# CardView in Grid not displaying shadow on all sides

Tags: android, gridview, android-cardview, cardview

I have recently dropped the idea of adding shadow to  `GridView` items and implemented `CardViews`.

The issue I am facing is the following: the `CardView` items display no shadow at the borders of the `GridView` as shown in the picture below:

[image]

The `CardView` Preview in Android Studio shows the layout with borders on all sides, shown as in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo7va.jpg).

**How can I add shadow to the sides of the GridView as well? Why is there no shadow coming from the `Cardview` items?**

I tried reducing/increasing the size of GridView columns, I tried adding `margin` and `padding` to the `GridView`. I tried adding larger margin to the `Cardview`. None of them worked.

This is the code for the `GridView`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/CatalogGridList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="128dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="8dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[This](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/187cd84cf4351b3ac1ad954d33557ab5) is the gist for the CardView layout xml.

Comment: try  android:padding="" property  in GrideView tags

Comment: @AmeerHamza As I said in my post, adding padding increases white space on the GridView's margins. No shadow coming from the `CardView`

Comment: try to convert android:layout_width="match_parent" this wrap_contant then use padding

Comment: @AmeerHamza I am affraid that doesn't fix it as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to use the `android:clipToPadding` attribute together with horizontal padding. Add these attributes to your `GridView` tag:

```
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
```

Without setting `clipToPadding="false"` you'll see the white bars you mentioned, but with it you'll see this:

[image]

Comment: This is the answer i was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @Ameer said, you need to add some padding on the containing `GridView` so as to allow space for the shadows. Adjust the padding properties(left and right) as you see fit:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/CatalogGridList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:columnWidth="128dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="8dp"/>
```

Comment: If i add padding as you suggest, and as I said in my post, I only get white spaces on the sides.  [This is the proof](http://imgur.com/a/y29Ft)